# GnuPG - Symmetric crypt with a null key

Tags: gnupg

As the title tells it, is it possible, using GnuPG, to do a symmetric encryption on a file, using a "null" key so when you do a `gpg --output doc --decrypt foo`, it'll decrypt it without asking for a password/passphrase ?

If not possible, is there a way, still with GnuPG, to make a PGP message that wouldn't need any password to decrypt it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why in the universe would you want to do _that_?

Comment: I found a file containing a PGP message that I was able to "decrypt" without using any password ( I haven't even been asked to submit something ), the file decrypted itself, so I wanted to know how to make such a thing

Comment: Check it yourself ; https://pastebin.com/bDHKm0M6

Comment: Note that the pastebin content has been removed.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tb2CzgiB ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There are two ways to create such a message. Either you can sign a message with the signature in the message and with `--clearsign` not specified, or you can use `--store`.**

### Signed but unencrypted

As for the specific message you provided, it is not an encrypted message, it is a signed message, not using a clear text signature. In other words, the signature and message are fused together. See [section 1.1.2](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Operational-GPG-Commands.html) of the GnuPG manual, which explains clear text signatures created with the `--clearsign` option. What you are seeing is a signature for an unencrypted file which is *not* using this type of signature. As a result, PGP-compatible software is required to read the file, despite it being unencrypted. This allows you to ensure integrity without requiring a decryption key.

You can create a message with a clear text signature easily:

```
$ md5sum message.txt
ecccffe1886ca709442672e65d66b409  message.txt
$ gpg --armor --sign message.txt
```

And then to access it again, you "decrypt" it:

```
$ gpg --decrypt message.txt.asc > message2.txt
$ md5sum message2.txt
$ ecccffe1886ca709442672e65d66b409  message2.txt
```

Or you can simply verify the signature:

```
$ gpg --verify message.txt.asc
gpg: Signature made Sat 30 Dec 2017 06:06:52 AM UTC using RSA key ID 8085AFFB
gpg: Good signature from "Test Key"
```

### Store only

There is a way to create a message without a signature either, using `--store`. This option is effectively equivalent to symmetric encryption with a null cipher. It stores the message encoded with an RFC1991 [literal data packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1991#section-6.1). If your goal is simply to create an unencrypted message, this is probably what you want. It does not guarantee either integrity or confidentiality.

Store the message in PGP format, without encryption:

```
$ md5sum message.txt
ecccffe1886ca709442672e65d66b409  message.txt
$ gpg --armor --store message.txt
```

And "decrypt" the message:

```
$ gpg -d message.txt.asc > message2.txt
$ md5sum message2.txt
ecccffe1886ca709442672e65d66b409  message2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Exactly what I was looking for :)